# Java 17: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am trying to Code my own little Game Engine, using **LWJGL**. So I got my Test "Game" running and decided to clean it up a bit by moving some code around, it all worked until I moved the actual Game Code to another Class. There were no Compilation Errors, but after running it, I got this:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd5363cde9, pid=42452, tid=9012
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (17.0.2+8) (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.2+8-LTS-86, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [nvoglv64.dll+0xcdcde9]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\[my-name]\Aspect\hs_err_pid42452.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

**hs_err_pid42452.log :**

I uploaded the log file to github because of the post character limit: https://github.com/mat4f/aspect/blob/main/hs_err_pid42452.log

I have no clue what any of that means. Does someone know what the Problem is?

I Uploaded the Source Code to github:
https://github.com/mat4f/aspect/tree/main/Aspect%20-%20The%20Broken%20One

I also did some debuging and the line it crashes is:

```java
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertices.length, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

The Problem was apparently that I was trying to Update the window and then Render stuff.

Now its first

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
shader.bind();
mesh.render();
shader.unbind();
```

and then

```
 glfwPollEvents();
```

I also Upgraded to JDK-19, but I don't think that has made any difference.